# Restarting the Ngnix

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I am a complete beginner to nginx. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I followed the steps,

1. sudo apt-get update.
2. sudo apt-get install nginx
3. sudo apt-get upgrade
4. sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default(here i found a file with
   default configuration as below)

   ```
   server {

   listen 8080 default_server;
   listen[::]: 8080 default_server;
   root /var/www/html;
   index index.html index.htm index.nginx - debian.html;

   server_name _;

   location / {
   try_files $uri $uri / = 404;
   }
   }
   ```

then i started the nginx, using

> sudo service nginx start

It shows the welcome page of nginx. Now i changed the root, like,

```
server {
      listen 8080 default_server;
      listen[::]: 8080 default_server;
      root /home/user1/folder1/dist; //this is the path i want to insert in nginx
      index index.html;

      server_name _;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri / = 404;
      }
    }
```

now  when i resart the ngnix, i had a problem that,

> user1@admin-xxx:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ sudo
>   service nginx restart 
>   **stop: Unknown instance:  nginx stop/pre-start,process 4726**

why here i am getting this pre-start, how to prevent this?, what does this mean?, and i want to restart the nginx. Can anyone please tell me how to force stop the nginx and to restart it? As a beginner i could not figure it out,. please help me out..

Comment: Do you really put `//this is the path i want to insert in nginx` in your nginx config? The comment should begin with `#`

Comment: no i didn't insert that comment, just to convey my issues here, i did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually use sudo nginx -s reload. Before restart, use sudo nginx -t to make sure the configuration is correct.

Comment: ya i did sudo nginx -t, this shows me what error i did it in the configuration file, thank you, really helped, it fixed my issue